# Trying to allow a device access to the Internet through ufw using a shared ethernet port on Raspberry Pi while on Wi-Fi

Tags: linux, networking, raspberry-pi, connection-sharing, ufw

I'm attempting to share my Raspberry Pi's ethernet port so I can connect an ethernet device (indirectly) to Wi-Fi while still protecting the device (and Pi) with a firewall (in this case ufw with gufw frontend using the "Public" profile). Assuming it's important, I'm using the latest Raspberry Pi OS (64-bit) build.

Here's what I've done so far:

- Edited the "Wired connection 1" entry using NetworkManager, changing the "Method" field under the IPv4 Settings to "Shared to other computers", ditto IPv6 Settings just for good measure. (So far so good with the firewall disabled, the laptop can browse the web)
- Enabled ufw via gufw. (Now the laptop doesn't get an IP from the Pi, as expected)
- `sudo ufw allow in on eth0 from 10.42.0.0/24 to 0.0.0.0/0` (or its equivalent with the gufw ui)
- `sudo ufw reload` now the laptop gets an IP from the Pi (in the 10.42.0.0/24 subnet, NetworkManager's default) and can ping Google, but can't browse the web ("This site can't be reached").

I don't care that I can't ping the laptop from the Pi, but what am I missing to ensure that the laptop can reach the Internet?

Comment: Have you looked at a packet capture, to see what's being sent/received that doesn't match the 'ufw allow's you've done?

Comment: @u1686_grawity That's some timing! I just updated this question with the solution I found, which works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the missing piece was IP Forwarding. To do so I followed an instruction found elsewhere which says to change `/etc/default/ufw` by modifying the value `"DROP"` in the line `DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="DROP"` to `"ACCEPT"` and then reload ufw.

This doesn't resolve IPv6 due to the lack of IPv6 firewall rule in my original question, but that's not important to me.